# Is there a way to backfill historical data (once) for a new Flow in Prefect?

Tags: etl, prefect

I just started reading about Prefect (and have a little experience using Airflow).

My goal is to set a task which runs daily in Prefect and collects data to a folder (I guess that's what Prefect can help me do for sure).
Also my goal is to populate the historical data (as if I ran this job back in time).

In Airflow there is this concept of start_date which when set in the past, the DAG will run since that date and populate on each interval.

For example, if I have a task which takes a date and returns the data for that date, such as:

```
# Pseudo code
def get_values_from_somewhere(date: datetime) -> dict:
    return fetched_values_in_json(date)
```

Is there a native way to do this in Prefect?
I could not find this answered anywhere in here or the docs, though backfilling is mentioned [here](https://docs.prefect.io/core/faq.html#does-prefect-support-backfills).
Any help / guidance will be super useful.

What I tried:

When I set `schedule` to be:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from prefect.schedules import Schedule

schedule = Schedule(clocks=[IntervalClock(interval=timedelta(hours=24), start_date=datetime(2019, 1, 1))])
```

and then I do `flow.run()` I simply get:

```
INFO:prefect.My-Task:Waiting for next scheduled run at 2020-09-24T00:00:00+00:00
```

What I was expecting is to run since the `start_date` which I have provided and then pause until it reaches present time and wait for the next schedule.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Prefect does not make any implicit assumptions about how your Flow or its Tasks depend on time, and therefore performing a backfill depends on the structure of your Flow.  There are generally two ways that time *explicitly* influences a Flow:

- through a `Parameter` or `DateTimeParameter`
- through `prefect.context` (which includes many time-related fields, described [here](https://docs.prefect.io/api/latest/utilities/context.html))

Given that, performing a backfill can be achieved by creating any number of ad-hoc scheduled flow runs and overriding either the appropriate context key or the default parameter value.  (Note that ad-hoc runs can be created for any flow, regardless of whether that flow has a schedule.)

To make this more precise, here are two examples that trigger a single backfill run (to accommodate more runs, loop over the appropriate values and create a run for each):

#### Using Context

```py
import pendulum
import prefect


@prefect.task
def do_something_time_specific():
    """
    This task uses the timestamp provided to the custom `backfill_time`
    context key; if that does not exist, it falls back on the built-in
    `scheduled_start_time` context key.
    """

    current_time = prefect.context.get("backfill_time") or prefect.context.get("scheduled_start_time")
    if isinstance(current_time, str):
        current_time = pendulum.parse(current_time)
    # performs some action dealing with this timestamp


flow = Flow("backfill", tasks=[do_something_time_specific])

## using Core
flow.run() # will use current timestamp
flow.run(context={"backfill_time": "1986-01-02"}) # will use old timestamp

## using an API
prefect.Client().create_flow_run(flow_id="FLOWID", 
    context={"backfill_time": "1986-01-02"}) # will use old timestamp
```

#### Using a Parameter

```py
import pendulum
import prefect


current_time = prefect.Parameter("current_time", default=None)

@prefect.task
def do_something_time_specific(current_time):
    """
    This task uses the timestamp provided to the task explicitly.
    """
    current_time = current_time or pendulum.now("utc") # uses "now" if not provided
    if isinstance(current_time, str):
        current_time = pendulum.parse(current_time)

    # performs some action dealing with this timestamp


with Flow("backfill") as flow:
    do_something_time_specific(current_time)


## using Core
flow.run() # will use current timestamp
flow.run(current_time="1986-01-02") # will use old timestamp

## using an API
prefect.Client().create_flow_run(flow_id="FLOWID", 
    parameters={"current_time": "1986-01-02"}) # will use old timestamp
```

Newer parameter classes such as `DateTimeParameter` provide nicer typing guarantees, but hopefully this demonstrates the idea.

**EDIT**: For completeness, note that ad-hoc runs can be created in Core for flows with schedules by running `flow.run(run_on_schedule=False)`

Comment: Hi @chriswhite, I tried what you suggested and using Context > Core, when I try and ass the `current_time` in the function `do_something_time_specific` it simply passes the time now (not the time which is fed via `flow.run(context={"intended_backfill_start_time": "1986-01-02"})`. That's not expected, right?

Comment: I could not get it to run via the API flow, as I got the following error: `ClientError: [{'message': "Variable '$input' got invalid value 'FLOWID' at 'input.flow_id';...`

Comment: I get same (no backfill results) via the Parameter too. Regardless of whether I use `flow.run()` or `flow.run(current_time="1986-01-02")` the `current_time` in `do_something_time_specific` is always the same : /

Comment: Hi @Newskooler - there was a typo in the task.  The dictionary keys need to match, I've updated accordingly.

The `FLOWID` value was a placeholder for a real flow ID from your Prefect backend.